# Evaluate NUnit assertion after a delay

Tags: c#, nunit, assert, assertion

I'm trying to write a unit test with NUnit for a method that could take anywhere from 1 to 3 seconds to complete. In order to valid the test all I need to do is check if a `List<string> entries` has been incremented in that 1 to 3 second span.

My current solution is to use a `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
1. int currentEntries = entries.count;
2. Call methodA()
3. Thread.Sleep(3000);
4. int updatedEntries = entries.count;
5. Assert.That(updatedEntries, Is.EqualTo(currentEntries+1));
```

This solution always takes at least 3 seconds, even when methodA() finishes faster.

I have tried using NUnits Delay constraint:

```
Assert.That(entries.Count, Is.EqualTo(currentEntries+1).After(3).Seconds.PollEvery(250).MilliSeconds);
```

This would have been ideal, since it supports polling. But the `After` constraint is still evaluated instantly instead of after 3 seconds, as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nunit-discuss/UtxlPa2czHU/_l06k5ggf54J).

Is there a better solution to this issue?

Comment: Or use async await and just wait for the method to complete and do your assertion after

Comment: The question in its current state does not provide enough details about the subject under test. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to `Assert.That` has an actual argument, which is evaluated immediately before the method is called. The value of `entries.Count` is taken and the resulting integer value is copied as the method argument. Within the method, we are dealing with a constant.

When the constraint is re-evaluated every 250 milliseconds, it is done each time against that same copied constant, which of course never changes.

When you use a delayed constraint, with or without polling, the actual argument has to be in the form of a delegate, a lambda or a reference to a field. The following simple modification should make it work.

```
Assert.That (() => entries.Count, Is.EqualTo(currentEntries+1).After(3).Seconds.PollEvery(250).MilliSeconds);
```

Alternatively, this should work as well

```
Assert.That (entries, Has.Count.EqualTo(currentEntries+1).After(3).Seconds.PollEvery(250).Milliseconds);
```

because the property is evaluated each time we poll.

Comment: Using `Has.Count.EqualTo` is also a cleaner approach

Answer (score 1):

Charlie's answer nails your actual problem (as his answers always do). However, I'd strongly recommend against having tests which depend upon delays. If your test fails, how will you know whether the problem was that you just didn't wait long enough.

Also, if this is part of an automated test suite, the elapsed time for executing all the tests will become extremely expensive as you add more tests like this.

Good tests are deterministic. For example, see Martin Fowler's [Eradicating Non-Determinism in Tests](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html), which includes the phrase:

> Never use bare sleeps to wait for asynchonous responses: use a callback or polling.

My suggestion would be to refactor your code so that the functionality is separated from the threading, and test the functionality, not the threading part.

Once this separation is achieved, the code which calls the functionality on a thread can be given a Mock, and you can simply verify that the Mock was called, since you have separately tested that it behaves correctly, although that still requires polling...so:

If you encapsulate the code which launches the separate thread, then in your test, provide a mocked thread launcher which actually executes the code synchronously. So as soon as the code being tested has completed, you can make the assertion, without waiting.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm writing these units tests in preparation for refactoring some legacy code. Thanks for the Fowler link, things to keep in mind during the refactoring.

Comment: I agree completely with the notion of deterministic tests, with exceptions for times when you are testing something that isn't designed the way it should be :-) as well as for integration tests. Hard to know when to give this kind of advice or just answer the question as asked. Between us, we nailed both!